# dynamic cookie domain with php

Tags: php, session-cookies

I want to be able to set the cookie params domain name dynamically.  I am setting this to .test.com - which would include all subdomains.

I want to use something like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in its place, but this is going to return www.test.com which would not be suitable for entering the correct value.

How can I go about doing this?

```
<?php

// start the session and timer
session_name('Site_Login');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.com', false, true);
session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/../../user-sessions'));
session_start();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"www")){
    $SERVER_NAME = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 4);
}else {
    $SERVER_NAME = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

Print $SERVER_NAME where you would like to print the url:

ex: www.test.com turns into  test.com

Comment: Only when $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is the www version of the domain.  If you are browsing from the non-www version this obviously won't work.

Comment: Updated. There ya go.

Comment: what if we use if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"www") >=0)